# Possible to upload / modify integer values for an entire column to string values in BigQuery SQL?

Tags: sql, join, casting, integer, concatenation

I am working many data tables where after several months, there are now letters instead of just integers in the values for one of the columns. It's inconvenient as the first 8 months are auto-detected as integers while the rest of the data has string values in a particular column. As I'm trying to create a comprehensive data table, I'm unable to join the two sets of data because the columns are incompatible. I would like to work with either strings or integers but I would prefer not to omit the letter values as they are unique identifiers.

e.g.

Dataset with integers:

[console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?ws=!1m5!1m4!4m3!1sdivvy-bike-data-391804!2sDivvy_bike_data_2!3sA202004](https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?ws=!1m5!1m4!4m3!1sdivvy-bike-data-391804!2sDivvy_bike_data_2!3sA202004)

```
column name : start_station_id
628
628
628
...
```

Dataset with strings:

[console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?ws=!1m5!1m4!4m3!1sdivvy-bike-data-391804!2sDivvy_bike_data_2!3sA202203](https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?ws=!1m5!1m4!4m3!1sdivvy-bike-data-391804!2sDivvy_bike_data_2!3sA202203)

```
start_station_id:
624
TA1306000029
TA1306000029
TA1308000043
...
```

Example of Final Data Table:

[console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?ws=!1m5!1m4!4m3!1sdivvy-bike-data-391804!2sDivvy_bike_data_2!3sTotal_Data](https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?ws=!1m5!1m4!4m3!1sdivvy-bike-data-391804!2sDivvy_bike_data_2!3sTotal_Data)

The error I'm recieving when trying to use

```
INSERT INTO divvy-bike-data-391804.Divvy_bike_data_2.Total_Data 
SELECT * FROM Divvy_bike_data_2.A202012
```

is

"Query column 6 has type STRING which cannot be inserted into column start_station_id, which has type INT64 at [2:5]"

Ideally, I would like to perform this on the entire column and there are hundreds of thousands of rows. Ideally, it could be done to multiple columns in the same query. Is there an easy workaround to this that you can think of? I appreciate any help in advance!

Sorry, I'm new to SQL so something that see easy may be right in front of my eyes, I just can't seem to find the one that works right.

Best,

Kyle

I've tried the concat function trying to add a letter to form a string, cast function, I've thought about adding another column with all a specific letter to try and join.

Comment: what would be the end result? of the table sql has no datasets

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking - *I would like to perform this* - what is *this* referring to? Please show your data and the desired result.

Comment: I would like to have a "final" table that has all of the data from multiple tables combined. It works well when there are only strings in the start_station_id column, but doesn't work trying to combine the tables that have integers. I would like to convert all the integers in the first 8 months of data to strings.

Basically, making a giant data table to use with R for visualization from lots of smaller ones without losing the letters from the string files.  I'll update the question to reflect this more clearly and include the data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert start_station_id to string:

```
INSERT INTO divvy-bike-data-391804.Divvy_bike_data_2.Total_Data 
SELECT A, B, C, Cast(start_station_id as STRING) as start_station_id FROM Divvy_bike_data_2.A202012
```

And Make sure start_station_id in Total_Data is string type too